# problem with mouseover and hiding some elements

Tags: jquery, css, blueprint-css

I'm trying to use jquery and blueprint css to do a (so i thought) simple task, which is illustrated in the code below. Basically, I have a list of items, and I want to have a X at the end of each item so that the items can be deleted, i would also want the X appearing only if the user mouseover the list items. The mouseover part works somewhat, but when i go near the X to click, it disappears for some reason. Blueprint css is used for positing. The code is as follows, it should just work if plugged into a blank html file:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .delete{
        display:none;
    }
    .entry{
        list-style:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/raw/63795c8bfe31cbbfad726f714bf8d22770adc7ad/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.entry').live("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).find('.delete').css({'display':'inline'});
        }).live('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).find('.delete').css({'display':'none'});
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<div id="list span-24 last">
<ul>
    <li class="entry"><div class="span-22">Something some thing some thing some thing some thing</div><div class="span-2 last"><a class="delete">X</a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `span` class applies a `float:left` to the element it's applied to. In your case, since you have the `span` inside of your `li`, the `li` has no height—it's filled with floating elements.

I'm not a whiz when it comes to the event bubbling of javascript, but I'm assuming the reason that it's working at all is that the event is bubbling up only when you are rolling over the `span-22`, and the second you get off of it, since the `li` has no height, you won't ever be able to roll on to your delete.

Long story short, you could either give a height to your `li` or apply the blueprint `.clearfix` class to all of the `li`s.

EDIT: There are probably other ways to fix this, but these are the first that come to mind.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly. Assign correct size to elements and clear floats of the elements. I have had similar problem with drop down menus - submenu opened wheni moved over 1st level li, but closed when i moved over 2nd level. All there was, was that 1st level li had no size set.